# Junit and Hibernate unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, junit

I can't understand why in the my unit tests with Junit in the setup method I have to add sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush(); sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear(); otherwise Hibernate will have some unexpected behaviour.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws ParseException
{

... saving data in the db
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();

}

@Test
@Transactional
public void getData() throws ParseException
{

    Set<Data> offers = productDao.getData(1);
}
```

In my getData() method I retrieve one object from the database

```
@Override
public Set<Data> getData(int id)
{

Offer offer = product.getOffer();
        if (offer != null)
        {
    Set<Product> productsOffers = offer.getProducts();
            for (Product productsOffer : productsOffers)
            {
                Set<ProductLicense> productLicences = productsOffer.getProductLicenses(); (**)
                for (ProductLicense productLicence : productLicences)
                {

    ...
   }
```

I can't understand why in ( ** ) the collection productLicenses is loaded if in the setUp I add sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush(); sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear(); , while if I omit these 2 lines in the setup method I get a null pointer exception in the line after (**).

Comment: I guess that when using ```@Transactional``` you are creating transaction in different context than what you get in the ```@Before``` method. Check if the contexts are the same.

Comment: Why? can you explain more?

Comment: I don't know why does that happen, but the behavior you describe would point to having different contexts. How is the ```productDao``` created? Is it autowired?

Comment: Did you try putting the ```@Transactional``` annotation on the whole class, not on the tests itself? Maybe that's why the ```@Before``` method is rolled back before the test.

Comment: it doesn't help, by the way, the objects that I save in the setUp() method not rolled back